# Can I set up template inheritance inside a template? (Template Toolkit)

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I have to display different medical forms according to which state the user is in.  There is also a default form that many of the states share.  These medical forms are all written in Template Toolkit and they are included in larger templates.  The state is available as a variable in a normalized form.

I need to select the state-specific template, if it exists, otherwise fall back to the default.  How would I best go about doing this?

`INCLUDE_PATH` is already being used to control switching between site styles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

main.tt:

```
This is a main template [% GET state %]
[% SET iname = state _ ".tt" %]
[% TRY %]
[% INCLUDE "$iname" %]
[% CATCH %]
[% INCLUDE default.tt %]
[% END %]
End of main template
```

default.tt:

```
This is default template
```

s1.tt:

```
This is template for state s1.
```

t.pl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use 5.006;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Template;
my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process("main.tt", { state => "s1" })
  || die $tt->error, "\n";
print "---------\n";
$tt->process("main.tt", { state => "unknown" })
  || die $tt->error, "\n";
```

When running `t.pl`:

```
This is a main template s1
This is template for state s1.
End of main template
---------
This is a main template unknown
This is default template
End of main template
```

Comment: That looks like it'll work, thanks!  And I can abstract it away into a utility template so I can do something like `[% INCLUDE "util/bystate" template = "some_form.tt2" ]`